# only surface charge is there for a conductor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I found that net charge density in the interior of a conductor is zero.The charge resides only on the surface.Then can we say that there is no volume charge density of any uniformly charge conductor?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have mobile charges in a uniform conductor leading to currents $\vec j=\sigma \vec E$, where the conductivity is related to carrier density, mobility and elementary charge by $\sigma=ne\mu$ there will be (in static equilibrium) no charge density and electric field in the interior. All charges of the conductor reside on the surface and these surface charges are such that they reduce any internal electric field of the conductor to zero.

One can, however, introduce local fixed charges in the interior (like local doping in semiconductors) which can lead to local fixed space charges.